# Linked android app to existing website's database

Tags: android, ios, ruby-on-rails, database

I have a rails 3 application which allows users to search objects into my database.

Now, I want to develop an Android application with PhoneGap which does the same search.

I do not know how one is supposed to do, so I thought to 2 means. Either I do get requests to my website to get json data, or either I develops a specific Android search which is linked to my database.

What is the right way to do it ? And how does big companies like Facebook or twitter to sent their data to Android or IOS since their database ?

Thanks and I hope not being excluding from the subjects of stackoverflow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before considering a proper route, you need to think the overall architecture of you project. Divide the architecture into tier. Once you finished dividing the application into tier, it will help you to understand how should you implement.

When you think about web application, it is clear that it would be hosted on web server. The database also will be on the same web server or separate server depends on the scale of project.

If you are viewing the search tools that you made on a browser and like to use browser toolkit on android or IOS for viewing the search web tool, you don't need to use any mediator application.

However, if you are trying to build an stand alone app, in order for you to access the search functionality from your app, you need to create a webservice. It could be json or any other. This json api will help you to mediate the communication between your client (Mobile app) and the database.

And this is how any big company would implement the project. It is always better to decouple your application logic. Loosely coupled application is easier to reuse. So creating a webservice would be ideal.